# Symfony 4 - Error 500 thrown instead of 403

Tags: exception, symfony4

I'm running Symfony 4/5, and for all my controllers in order to be able to execute the method I have an EventSubscriber that checks for the right permissions.

If the user is not granted, then it throws an `AccessDeniedHttpException`.
This works fine as the method is binded to a route.
But when rendering inside a twig template manually a controller action as :

```
{{ render( controller('App\\ExampleBundle\\Controller\\ChartsController::renderChart' ) }}
```

I got a 500 error instead of a 403.

I've debugged the app and checked that the exception as actually thrown, but the browser shows a 500 exception.

Is this a bug, or do I have to handle in another way the exception when it is for manually rendered methods from a twig template ?

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis for the `render()` function, that could be responsible for a syntax error and thus a 500.